# Is PHP Memcached thread safe?

Tags: php, multithreading, thread-safety, memcached

Should I be worried about one script modifying a "Memcached" entry while another is reading it?

I didn't find nothing in the [official documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php).

Comment: I think so, but I couldn't find any confirmation anywhere.

Comment: It would be a bad cache, which it isn't, if it wasn't thread safe. You can therefore assume it is.

Comment: I completely agree with you. However, I know from experience that I shouldn't take anything for granted. Especially when I see the quantity of aberrations and bugs in libraries developed by large companies. Nothing can surprise me anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is threadsafe. It is [based on libmemcached](https://www.php.net/manual/en/memcached.requirements.php) which itself states as threadsafe in the [documentation](http://docs.libmemcached.org/memcached_pool.html?highlight=thread#).

> Both memcached_pool_release() and memcached_pool_fetch() are thread safe.